# Arduino se cuelga, incluso con el watchdog activado

Tags: arduino

He desarrollado un equipo hardware basado en ATmega328P y que es programable con el IDE de Arduino

Este equipo dispone de una salida a relé que conmuta una carga AC.

De vez en cuando, el microcontrolador se reinicia cuando la carga se activa o desactiva. Hasta aquí, ningún misterio. Probablemente el causante del reinicio sea alguna interferencia electromagnética en la conmutación del relé

PERO, algunas veces el microcontrolador se cuelga completamente. No consigo saber por qué, puesto que el temporizador de watchdog está habilitado y funcionando. No debería haber ningún cuelgue. El watchdog debería reiniciar el micro después de 2 segundos

Necesitaría ayuda para entender por qué el microcontrolador se cuelga, incluso con el watchdog configurado, y por supuesto, saber si podría existir algún parche para solucionar esto.

Dejo aquí un código simple con el que reproduzco este comportamiento. He probado a cambiar configuraciones de fuses (brownout, wdton, etc.) pero hasta ahora no he conseguido que no se cuelgue

Muchas gracias de antemano

```
#include <avr/wdt.h>

#define R0 3
#define R1 4
#define R2 5

unsigned int delayTime = 200;
unsigned int counter   = 0;

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

void setup() {
  
  MCUSR = 0; 
  wdt_disable(); 
  
  Serial.begin (9600);
  delay (1000);
  Serial.println ("********************RESTARTING*****************");
  pinMode (R0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode (R1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (R2, OUTPUT);
  delay (2000);   
  
  wdt_enable (WDTO_2S);
  
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------

void loop() {
  
  wdt_reset();
  digitalWrite (R1, HIGH);
  counter++;
  Serial.print ("R1 activated, counter = "); Serial.println (counter);
  delay (delayTime);
  digitalWrite (R1, LOW);
  Serial.print ("R1 deactivated, counter = "); Serial.println (counter);
  delay (delayTime);
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Es extraordinariamente difícil que un Arduino se quede colgado. En varios años trabajando con ellos creo que nunca me ha pasado, incluso en procesos que corren por días y semanas (hasta que paran por corte de luz).

El código que publicas hace 3 a 4 pasadas por `loop` cada segundo, tiempo de sobra para alimentar el watchdog.

```
03:36:45.688 -> R1 activated, counter = 3761
03:36:45.887 -> R1 deactivated, counter = 3761
03:36:46.085 -> R1 activated, counter = 3762
03:36:46.284 -> R1 deactivated, counter = 3762
03:36:46.482 -> R1 activated, counter = 3763
03:36:46.681 -> R1 deactivated, counter = 3763
03:36:46.880 -> R1 activated, counter = 3764
03:36:47.081 -> R1 deactivated, counter = 3764
03:36:47.279 -> R1 activated, counter = 3765
```

**Brown out**

Descartando problemas eléctricos en el circuito mismo (cableado mal hecho, partes mal conectadas), la causa externa más probable del reset es un *brown out*, una breve caida en el voltaje.

Arduino se resetea por default cuando el voltaje baja de 2.7v, y el evento sólo necesita durar unos microsegundos.

¿Solución? Prueba con alimentación de batería, para descartar ruido en la alimentación AC.

Si tienes un osciloscopio, puedes usarlo para revisar la calidad de la alimentación. Si vas a trabajar con electrónica, incluso uno barato de bolsillo te sacara de más de un apuro, asi que vale la pena tener uno a mano.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. En realidad ya había probado a desactivar el brown out sin ningún resultado. El problema se solucionó activando el fuse WDTON (watchdog always ON) y evitando deshabilitar el watchdog manualmente en el setup